# Enabling a Sharepoint Feature with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell and have been asked to modify a script that is used to activate features on a site. The script has some latency issues between the two feature activations, so I decided to make a new function that will enable the feature and sleep or delay until the feature is finished enabling. Will this work? And if so, how can I tell that the feature is finished activating?

```
# This is a function that enable's a Sharepoint Feature and Sleeps Until Its Finished Enabling

function Feature-Enable

{param ([string]$ID, [string]$URL)

#Enable Feature

Enable-SPFeature -Identity $ID -url $URL -Confirm:$false

#Sleep Until Feature is Done Enabling

}

#Set parameters/variables for script
$serverName = "someServerName"
$rootwebUrl = "someRootUrl"

$currentpath=Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent

$siteURL = "http://" + $servername + $rootwebURL

$start = Get-Date -DisplayHint Time

# check to ensure Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is loaded

$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'}

if ($snapin -eq $null) {

Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"

Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"

}


#         Active Site Collection Features (in order)

        write-host ""

        write-host "----------------------------------------"

        write-host "Begin activation of site collection features"

        write-host "----------------------------------------"

        write-host ""

  Feature-Enable –identity "3cbf5d1e-ff2e-48d2-82a4-99b060381268" -URL $siteUrl


#NOTE:  POTENTIAL LATENCY ISSUES.   MAY NEED TO INSERT DELAY TIMER!

  Feature-Enable –identity "bbde524e-9293-468e-84f7-fdb763ffa309" -URL $siteUrl

        write-host ""

        write-host "----------------------------------------"

        write-host "Activation of site collection features - DONE!"

        write-host "----------------------------------------"

        write-host ""


$end= Get-Date -DisplayHint Time

Write-Host "Started at: " $start " Ended at:  " $end;
```

Comment: any final solution with full source code final sample?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know Enable-SPFeature will only continue when feature is enabled (or on error) so you don't need explicity check if it is enabled or not.

Not sure about your latency issues but you can check if your feature is enabled on site scope  with:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "[Your Site Url]"
if (Get-SPFeature -Site $site | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq "[Your feature ID]"}) {
    Write-Host "Feature is enabled"
} else {
    Write-Host "Feature is disabled"
}
```

But this snippet will always return true if you call it after Enable-SPFeature (I have tried on some simple features)